# How do i get the value of an input in php

Tags: php, jquery

I'm trying to update the database with the value of an input, but the input changed when a new image is the using jquery, so i want to get the value of the input using php and update my database with that value, I've tried, but so far it just updates the rows with 0,even if i change $_POST to $_GET, how can i go upon fixing this problem?

```
//Update the user team.
if (isset($_POST['f']) && $_POST['f'] == 'setTeam')  {


        $cid1 = $_POST['s0'];

        $cid2 = $_POST['s1'];

        $cid3 = $_POST['s2'];


$updateTeam = $db->query("UPDATE accounts SET cid1 = '$cid1', cid2 = '$cid2', cid3 = '$cid3' WHERE id = '$id'");



}
<div id="droppable_slots" class="current_team">
                    <div class="slot 1">1</div>
                    <input type="hidden" name="s0" value="">
                    <div class="slot 2">2</div>
                    <input type="hidden" name="s1" value="">
                    <div class="slot 3">3</div>
                    <input type="hidden" name="s2" value="">
                </div>
```

Updated version:

```
if (isset($_POST['f']) && $_POST['f'] == 'setTeam')  {


        $cid1 = $_GET['s0'];

        $cid2 = $_GET['s1'];

        $cid3 = $_GET['s2'];


$updateTeam = $db->query("UPDATE accounts SET cid1 = '$cid1', cid2 = '$cid2', cid3 = '$cid3' WHERE id = '$id'");



}
<form id="droppable_slots" name="droppable_slots" method="POST">
            <div class="slot 1">1</div>
            <input type="hidden" name="s0" value="">
            <div class="slot 2">2</div>
            <input type="hidden" name="s1" value="">
            <div class="slot 3">3</div>
            <input type="hidden" name="s2" value="">
        </form>
```

Comment: you are not adding input inside of `form` with `method="post"` so you can not access it using `$_POST`

Comment: What should i put there instead? $_GET doesn't work.

Comment: Can you show us the rest of the HTML (and javascript, if you are setting the hidden fields with js as well), or isolate an example that includes a `<form>` tag?

Comment: as i told you, you should wrap your `droppable_slots` `div` inside `<form method="post">`

Comment: Is this a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19330082/ajax-call-isnt-update-my-rows AND http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19307350/ajax-calling-isnt-working ???

Comment: @Sean, If he is posting the same thing over and over, raise a flag.

Comment: It was answered in the other question, my bad and thanks for the help

Answer (score 1):

```
<form id="droppable_slots" name="droppable_slots" method="POST">
                <div class="slot 1">1</div>
                <input type="hidden" name="s0" value="">
                <div class="slot 2">2</div>
                <input type="hidden" name="s1" value="">
                <div class="slot 3">3</div>
                <input type="hidden" name="s2" value="">
            </form>
```

Comment: can you please try to explain what OP should do..???

Comment: @DipeshParmar i am saying to use form inplace of div

Answer (score 0):

1. You should wrap inputs in form.
2. You should set value in hidden input. I suppose you use jquery for that.

Code should looks like this:

```
<form method="POST">
            <div class="slot 1">1</div>
            <input type="hidden" name="s0" value="">
            <div class="slot 2">2</div>
            <input type="hidden" name="s1" value="">
            <div class="slot 3">3</div>
            <input type="hidden" name="s2" value="">
        </form>
```

You should add `<input type="submit">` if you gonna submit it with pressing button on the form. If it happens somehow else - then write script with js that will submit it.

Your php script looks like correct.

Comment: forget to add submit button..???

Comment: @DipeshParmar he can submit it with js. As far as I understand it's not an explicit form. Thanks anyway. :)

Answer (score 0):

```
Use form tag and add attribute method="POST"
<form method="POST" name="update" action="">
<div id="droppable_slots" class="current_team">
                    <div class="slot 1">1</div>
                    <input type="hidden" name="s0" value="">
                    <div class="slot 2">2</div>
                    <input type="hidden" name="s1" value="">
                    <div class="slot 3">3</div>
                    <input type="hidden" name="s2" value="">
                </div>
</form>
```